# insert cloned rows into database using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have one original and 4 cloned rows of books details,

[image]

i have inserted first row into database using pdo but m not getting any idea how to insert cloned rows using loop.

code i have used is,

```
$books_booktitle = $_POST['booktitle'];
$books_bookgenre = $_POST['bookgenre'];
$books_bookwriter = $_POST['bookwriter'];
$books_bookdescription = $_POST['bookdescription'];
    $books_userid = $db->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bookdetails (BookTitle,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription,UserId) VALUES (:BookTitle, :BookGenre, :BookWriter, :BookDescription, :UserId)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':BookTitle', $books_booktitle);
    $stmt->bindParam(':BookGenre', $books_bookgenre);
    $stmt->bindParam(':BookWriter', $books_bookwriter);
    $stmt->bindParam(':BookDescription', $books_bookdescription);
    $stmt->bindParam(':UserId', $books_userid);
    $stmt->execute();
```

please do reply if you have any idea.

Comment: you can use jquery to collect value from input fields and then use ajax to send those data to php

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: i really don't have idea of parameters inside loop that's why i haven't included.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(...);
    ...
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't prepare in the loop; the `prepare` shouldn't change so prepare outside the loop. Bind and execute inside.

Comment: @chris85 You right, need prepare and execute in the loop

Comment: Just `execute` and `bind..` in the loop.

Comment: sorry but , the value of 5th row has been inserted in all five rows .

Comment: @Cooolranjan Do you need insert `UserId` to all different rows ?